# Warhammer 40,000 dawn of war soulstorm steam proton not launching

Tags: wine, games, steam

I am trying to play this game through steam play on ubuntu 18.04 but the game never launches. I have reinstalled nvidia driver 396 from repository and installed vulkan-utils.

Comment: Maybe run steam from terminal and look for any errors there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to launch options fixed it:

```
WINEPREFIX=$STEAM_LIBRARY/steamapps/compatdata/9450/pfx
```